# Why is convention and consistency important while working with data fields/names?

Tags: database, metadata, facebook-opengraph, convention, consistency

The issue is about good practice with database, form fields, and coding in general.

We run a content providing platform, much like Buzzfeed and Wired. I am currently implementing the OpenGraph meta tags for each posts, so that the post links are nicely presented in external websites such as Facebook.

A co-worker from the marketing team insisted that we should put something else other than title in the 'title' field for marketing reasons.

I argued that the Open Graph meta tags should truthfully represent the content of the link, to conserve consistency and convention - that the meta tags should not be considered 'one-off's.

However I couldn't further explain as to why I should! I'm not really good with words myself.

Most of the quarrels involve other workers wanting to 'hack' with perfectly fine APIs or implementations and I have to convince them why it is important to at least stay in the safe zone while possible.

I know convention and consistency is one of the most important practice with technology but I think I just got used to the fact and forgot my university lectures on why it is so.

Could I get some thoughts on this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A co-worker from the marketing team insisted that we should put something else other than title in the 'title' field for marketing reasons.

That's a valid decision. Your job is to help save costs or make money for the business. It is not your job to maintain the Facebook ecosystem as a whole. That's not what you are payed to do.

If you don't have any business reason why this should not be done you have no case. Such a reason could be that Facebook would penalize this or that this creates some development cost or risk.

If this is not a technical decision at all, and I see no reason it would be in the question, it's his decision anyway. In that case you need to inform him of the concerns that you see and let him decide.

Comment: Yeah. I think I might have gone a little ahead of myself. I'll have this in mind! Thanks for the perspective, I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

You clearly try to work in a mindset that lets self-discipline prevail over short-term gains and quick-and-dirty hacks.  Managing to do that is always beneficial in the long run, but convincing managers and/or sales people to let go of the short-term gain is never easy (on the contrary, most of the time it is simply impossible).

Just want to let you know that there are many, many IT folks who "feel your pain".  Don't give up your laudable mindset too easily.

Convention in naming makes for source code that is more readily understandable by others who follow the same conventions.  That in turn makes for less costlier maintenance.  Consistency in choosing "appropriate" names for things has similar benefits.  Saying on the tin what's inside (and not something completely different or something way too vague and ambiguous) is the best possible practice in computing, but it is the worst possible one in marketing.

Comment: Yeah, thank you for the point. I want to choose both answers but I feel that, as usr said, I may not have have respected the other's professions over mine. Really appreciate your point, though :)